# Why won't Capybara select the right item in a select menu?

Tags: rspec, capybara

When you `save_and_open_page`, you can see that my form contains:

```
<label class="select optional control-label" for="assignment_role_id">Role</label>
  <select class="select optional" id="assignment_role_id" name="assignment[role_id]">
    <option value="819">admin</option>
    <option value="820">customer</option>
</select>
```

Why, then, won't Capybara select the right item in the drop down menu? I get:

```
Failure/Error: select("customer", :from => :Role)
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot select option, no option with text 'customer' in select box 'Role'
```

...and...

```
Failure/Error: select("customer", :from => :assignment_role_id)
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot select option, no option with text 'customer' in select box 'assignment_role_id'
```

...and...

```
Failure/Error: select("customer", :from => :role_id)
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot select option, no option with text 'customer' in select box 'role_id'
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the line breaks within your `<option>` tags?

Comment: It's actually all on one line. I just spread it here out for readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was:

```
select("customer", :from => "assignment[role_id]")
```

Comment: If you're using Capybara, I recommend you familiarize yourself with the Actions, Finders and Matchers (http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node).  Here's the pertinent README: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method